# Groovy - Calling a method with def parameter fails with 'Illegal class name"

Tags: groovy

I am hoping to get an explanation as to why the call to this Groovy method works as expected:

```
def f1(int n) {
  return n + 1
}
println f1(1) // -> 2
```

But, if the parameter is not specifically defined ("def n" instead of "int n"), the method call needs to change:

```
def f2(def n) {
  return n + 1
}
println f2(1) // Exception: Illegal class name
println this.&f2(1) // -> 2
```

What is happening under the hood to make this necessary?

UPDATED with more info:

This is on Windows with Groovy 2.4.5 JVM 1.8.0_51

The entire script is those 9 lines in a file called 1.groovy - nothing else.

I am running this from the console (cmdr) using "groovy 1.groovy"

The error on line 8 is:

Caught: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "3$f2" in class file 3$f2
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "3$f2" in class file 3$f2
        at 3.run(3.groovy:8)

Comment: What about `def f3(n) {...`? Also what version of Groovy is this?

Comment: `f2(1)` works fine for me. Be aware that adding def to method params is totally unnecessary.

Comment: I don't have any issue with your example, tested in the groovy webconsole or in a java application. It's probably related to a context you didn't show here

Comment: This is on Windows with Groovy 2.4.5 JVM 1.8.0_51  - the entire script is those 9 lines. The error on line 8 is: Caught: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "3$f2" in class file 3$f2
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "3$f2" in class file 3$f2
        at 3.run(3.groovy:8)

Comment: doelleri - dropping the def from the parameter - def f2(n) {} - throws the exception, as well

Comment: jeremie - yes I just tried it in groovysh and it works - so what is different about running it in a script and calling "groovy scriptname"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is related to the name of your Script. When you have a file "1.groovy", Groovy generate a class with the name "1" in the default package, which is not a valid class name.

When you use `f2(n)` without a type, as this method is "too generic", Groovy try to find a matching method, or a class named `f2`, or an inner class named f2 : loading an inner class `f2` of the class `1` fail, because the name is invalid.

Comment: Excellent - that's it! The file was actually called 3.groovy and now I understand the error message

Comment: TIP: Another way around this issue is to wrap your method in a class with a valid name.

Comment: I just had the issue because I had a "-" in my filename. Replacing it with "_" fixed it. You saved my productivity of this afternoon. Thanks!

Comment: My groovy script had a hyphen in the name. Removing it solved the issue. Thanks @gturri